# In vim, problems while loading the indent script for tex files

Tags: vim, tex, auto-indent

I am trying to get the indent file for tex to work. I have a Ubuntu 14.04 install with vim 7.4.
I can manually load the indent script using :

```
source /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/tex.vim
```

But when I use

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

and I check :scriptnames, the aforementioned script is not listed and none is listed with the name "tex.vim". What is going on ?

Comment: What does `:set filetype?` show? Have you tried adding a modeline if the `.tex` suffix isn’t affecting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try put this command in your `vimrc` after the `filetype plugin indent on`:

```
autocmd FileType tex source /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/tex.vim
```